# How can I convert a pickled sklearn GBM classifier into an R GBM object?

Tags: python, r, gbm

I was given a pickled object with class `sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting.GradientBoostingClassifier`.  I also have a list of the feature names.

I need to convert that model into R's gbm model type. How can I do this?